# How to print an entire WPF Listbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, printing, listbox

I have a 3.5 WPF application in which I want to be able to print the contents of a listbox. I've noticed that when there are enough items that a vertical scroll bar is needed and the user scrolls down, it will not print anything above, like what they just scrolled past.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Dim pDialog As New PrintDialog
    Dim winPrint As Window = GetDowntimeWindow("PrintQueue")

    'Show the dialog to ask what printer to use
    If pDialog.ShowDialog() Then

        'Get the listbox to print
        Dim lbxLabels As ListBox = CType(winPrint.FindName("lbxLabels"), ListBox)

        pDialog.PrintVisual(lbxLabels, "Labels")

    End If
```

Comment: I neglected to mention that the scrollbar is a part of a ScrollViewer- I am not using the ListBox's scrollbar. I am still curious to know if there are any easy solutions to this, however I decided to snap the scollbar back to the top before printing. The users shouldn't take issue or even notice that that happened as there won't be a large number of items in the box.

Comment: `PrintVisual` prints WPF control visuals. I.e. it prints **what's on the screen**. This is problematic because if part of the control contents have not been rendered they will not be printed, it does not handle paginiation, it blocks the UI thread, and what looks good on screen often does not look good on paper. The right way to do this is to render the contents to `DrawingVisual`s and lay then out to a `DocumentPaginator`. Yes, this is a lot of work.

Comment: I just might have to attempt a more complex solution like you suggest. On my Windows 7 machine, I can't even get what is on the screen to print- it sets the printable width/height to 393 by 384 no matter what I am printing and I can't figure out how to change that. Seems to work ok on Windows Server, though.

Comment: Figured that one out- it was using the dimensions of the default printer. Whoops. So it's all working now as long as I call ScrollToTop() for the ScrollViewer object.